# OpenJpa query caching is not refreshing in case of null value

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, openjpa

I am facing some problem in OpenJpa second level caching. Most of times caching is working but in one particular case it is not working. Here is a scenario when it is not working,
When your code result null value then it store it into cache and then it never clear that value. Although it clears values only when query returns a value.

Here is code which I had written to get value from database,

```
List<PartnerapiworkflowEntity> partnerapiworkflowEntityList = null;
        try {
            partnerapiworkflowEntityList = entityManager.createQuery("select p from someentity p where p.id = :Id and p.name = :name and " +
                    "p.code = :Code and p.operationname = :operationName")
                    .setParameter("Id", Id)
                    .setParameter("name", name)
                    .setParameter("code", Code)
                    .setParameter("operationName", operationName).getResultList();//.getSingleResult();
            if(partnerapiworkflowEntityList != null && partnerapiworkflowEntityList.size() > 0){
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        } catch (NoResultException ne) {
            logger.severe("some logging info.");
        }
        finally {
//            entityManager.detach(partnerapiworkflowEntity);
        }
```

And here is a code which refresh cache.

```
try{
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
    entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
    //((JpaEntityManager)entityManager.getDelegate()).getServerSession().getIdentityMapAccessor().invalidateAll();
    entityManager.flush();

} catch (Exception e){
    throw e;
}
```

And this is persistence.xml code

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="mysql"/>
<property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true(EnableStatistics=true, CacheSize=10000, SoftReferenceSize=0, EvictionSchedule='+10')"/>
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="true(EvictPolicy='timestamp')"/>
<!--<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="true(EnableStatistics=true)"/>-->
<property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"/>

<property name="openjpa.Instrumentation" value="jmx(Instrument='DataCache,QueryCache,QuerySQLCache')"/>
<property name="openjpa.MetaDataRepository" value="Preload=true"/>

<property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=Trace" />
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrintParameters=true" />
```

Everything working fine when query always returns value. The problem is start when it return null value. Then first time is store in cache and then it never refresh.

I am using OpenJpa2 and Hibernate.

Comment: 1) How can do you use OpenJPA with Hibernate? 2) Your query cannot return `null` value, it can return an empty list. 3) How do you know that `null` value is stored in cache and never cleared, how did you inspect the cache content?

Comment: When you call single method then it return noResultExcepyion and in case of empty value. It also have same behaviour.

Comment: For your third question, I modified value in databases so that it must return value. After that I cleared cache. But still it returns same result while I am expecting a value from result.

Comment: It depends on whether you are using pre-JPA 2.0 level Open JPA lib.  Prior to JPA 2.0, there was no defined mechanism for working with a L2 cache.  Thus, OpenJPA 1.x provided their own API for performing this function. If it is port 2.0 > try removing flush after the evictAll.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was first observed with `OpenJPA 2.2.2`. Looking up online revealed that there was a defect that was fixed on trunk that was related to L2 cache (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2285)

But this problem is again found later in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2522

---

### Solution:

So far it is not fixed yet. But they have given some bypassing solution.

1. **Disable query cache**

To disable the query cache (default), set the `openjpa.QueryCache` property to false:

```
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="false"/>
```

2. **By configuring sql query cache to false**

   - To specify a custom cache class:

     `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="com.mycompany.MyCustomCache"/>`
   - To use an unmanaged cache:

     `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="false"/>`

   OR

   - To use an unmanaged cache:

     `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="all"/>`

---

3. [Open JPA - L2 Cache Issue and Workaround](https://dzone.com/articles/open-jpa-l2-cache-issue-and)

> This tutorial depicts your problem same to same. Here you can get the
>   clear conception of occuring this error.

It gives a solution that you must have to keep related data. So that `NullPointerException` will not arise. Data must be consistent until OpenJPA not solve the issue. :D

---

4. [Several mechanisms are available to the application to bypass SQL
   caching for a JPQL query.](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#jpa_caching_parametrize_jpql)

A user application can disable Prepared SQL Cache for entire lifetime of a persistence context by invoking the following method on OpenJPA's EntityManager SPI interface:

```
OpenJPAEntityManagerSPI.setQuerySQLCache(boolean)
```

5. Plug-in property `openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache` can be configured to
   exclude certain JPQL queries as shown below.

   `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.QuerySQLCache" value="true(excludes='select c from Company c;select d from Department d')"/>`

will never cache JPQL queries `select c from Company c` and `select d from Department d`.

### [Root Cause Analysis:](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rdyn_openjpa.html?lang=en)

The query cache stores the object IDs that are returned by query executions. When you run a query, JPA assembles a key that is based on the query properties and the parameters that are used at launch time and checks for a cached query result. If one is found, the object IDs in the cached result are looked up, and the resulting persistence-capable objects are returned. Otherwise, the query is launched against the database and the object IDs that are loaded by the query are placed into the cache. The object ID list is not cached until the list that is returned at query launch time is fully traversed.

### [IBM Recommendation:](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tejb_datcacheconfig.html?lang=en)

> L2 caching increases the memory consumption of the application,
>   therefore, it is important to limit the size of the L2 cache. There is
>   also a possibility of stale data for updated objects in a clustered
>   environment. Configure L2 caching for read-mostly, infrequently
>   modified entities. L2 caches are not recommended for frequently and
>   concurrently updated entities.

### Resource Link:

[Open JPA 2.4.0 Caching Reference Guide](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_caching.html)

Comment: I don't want to disbale query cache as it is required to improve performance.

Comment: On that case, you can follow No. 5 or make sure that related data is exists which is described in No. 3 @Awadhendra

Comment: @No, You can not make sure this. Those are configuration value which comes from some onboarding API. You cannot control whether those value exists or not.

Comment: @Awadhendra Had you go through No. 3. What about that ?

Answer (score 1):

You are evicting entries, but what about query cache? It can be that in normal case evicting is noticed by query case, so the result is invalidated... It can explain why null fails here. Can you please confirm?

EDIT:

```
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="false"/>
```

Means no query cache. My bad.

Other try - [NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html) check? You have query, with params - can you execute it directly on the database?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I am getting problem in case, when query cache return null value. It is not refreshing that value. All other cache is invalidated except the one query which returns null value.

Comment: I have to use query cache. So I can not set this configuration in code. Only thing which I want when I clear cache then it should clear it all.

Comment: But you provided that configuration entry... can you confirm that provided `persistance.xml` is the one we are talking about?

Comment: I had updated configuration entry. Sorry for that mistake.